# How do I duplicate my repo hosted in github to a repo hosted somewhere else?

Tags: git, github

I have a github repository with some work inside.

I have been asked to push this work to another host.

So far, I added the other remote to my local repository:

```
git remote -v 
    apt   URL (fetch)
    apt   URL (push)
    origin  URL (fetch)
    origin  URL (push)
```

`Origin` is the original repo I used, `apt` is the new remote repository.

However, in the new (`apt`) remote, there is already a readme (created by default), and I do not have the permission to git push -f to the (nearly) empty new remote.

My guess is that I should merge/rebase the master of the `origin` with the master of `apt`. I am "afraid" to do stuff because I am not sure how git will behave handling two branches with the same name (if such a thing is possible).

**How can I push my work, present on origin/master, to apt/master ?**

Answer (score 0):

A simple `git push` will push the current branch to it's default repository.

To push to a specific repository, just add it's name to the invocation:

```sh
git push apt
```

BTW, this is documented in the manual for `git push`, which you can invoke with:

```sh
git push --help
```